# Tomcat returns wrong path for AppData

Tags: java, tomcat, environment-variables

I am using 3rd party tool built in node for my project build in java. That 3rd party tool is by default installed in

> C:\Users\ZXC\AppData\Roaming\npm\xyz

When I run my code in Eclipse it runs fine and gives me correct path of **AppData** using

> System.getenv("AppData")

but this same code when run on tomcat gives me this path

> C:\Windows\System32\config\AppData\Roaming

This path is incorrect, there is no AppData folder inside this config folder either. Is there something I am missing, or System.getenv won't work on tomcat?

Comment: I was unable to reproduce your problem. Can you provide more information: [1] Windows version [2] Tomcat version [3] JRE version [4] Are you running Tomcat as a Windows service, or starting it from the command line?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is because when you're running the application in Eclipse, the owner of the process is your Windows user - **ZXC**, whereas running Tomcat as a service, it most probably runs it as LocalSystem, and `%AppData%` default location is **different for each user**.

Correct way to pass environment variable to Tomcat, without being dependant on user-specific paths would be to create a file `CATALINA_BASE/bin/setenv.bat` or `CATALINA_HOME/bin/setenv.bat`  for Windows (setenv.sh for *nix environment) and inside of it, set any variable that you might need to use inside of your application. In this case, the content should look something like this:

```
set “PATH_TO_TOOL=C:\Users\ZXC\AppData\Roaming\npm\xyz"
```

and then use in your application `PATH_TO_TOOL` variable (or choose better naming) to avoid any possible further problems because of the specifics of `AppData` user variable. You can see more details about the usage of `setenv` script in [Tomcat documentation](https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-8.0-doc/RUNNING.txt).